# Getting value of a field in a form in yii from ajax

Tags: php, ajax, drop-down-menu, yii

I have a problem, i'm quite a newbie in yii and i suck in ajax.
Suppose i have a form in yii looks like:

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownListRow($model,'study_type_id', $studyTypeList, array(
        'options'=>array($default['studyTypeId']=>array('selected'=>true)),
        'id'=>'study-type-list',
        'class'=>'span5 study-create-input')
); ?>
```

say options in the drop down are "studytype1","studytype2"..and so on..

how do i access those options in string form..(sorry for the bad explanation)..in an ajax script say..

```
 Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('generateStudyName', "
        var updateStudyName = function() {

 var studyType = ??//I want to access the value selected in the drop down list
 that i hope to use

}");
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#study-type-list').val()` will give you the selected value of the drop down element.

Use this to get the selected options text.

```
$('#study-type-list option:selected').text();
```